# Multiple forms in one page update concrete block?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

As you can see from the picture I have several forms in one page. Each of this form has there own block with list of comments.

I am tring with AJAX/JQuery update block of comments after succesfull adding new comment by form. Lets say if user add comment by 3-d form AJAX need update 3-d comments block which is under 3-d form. Here below you can see my JS code.

The problem is when I use the same id for all forms (task-comment-form) and the same id for all comments block (task-comments) works well only first form. When I submit second or third form it update first comment block. I think JS checks the document from top to bottom and finds the first match.

When I use  the same class for all forms and comment blocks it works wrong too. For example when I submit second form all 3 comment block updates.

**So how to associate a particular form with a specific comment block?**

[image]

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.submit').on("click", function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(event.preventDefault());
        var form = $(this).closest('form');
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr("action"),
            data: form.serialize(),
            type: form.attr("method"),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.form_is_valid) {
                    $("#task-comments").html(data.html_task_comment);
                }
                else {
                    $("#task-comment-form").html(data.html_task_comment_form);
                }
            }
        });
        $("#task-comment-form")[0].reset();
        return false;
    });
});
```

**task_list.html:**

```
<div class="list-group custom-list-group">
   <div class="list-group-item bg-faded">
      {% include 'project/task_comment_form.html' %}
   </div>
   <div id="task-comments-{{ forloop.counter }}">
      {% include 'project/task_comment_list.html' %}
   </div>
</div>
```

**task_comment_form.html:**

```
<form method="post" id="task-comment-form-{{ forloop.counter }}" action="{% url 'project:task_comment_add' project_code=project.code group_task_code=group_task.code task_code=task.code %}">
     <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

**task_comment_list.html:**

```
{% for comment  in task.comments.all %}
    <div class="list-group-item flex-column align-items-start">
        <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
            <h6 class="mb-1">{{ comment.author }}</h6>
            <small>{{ comment.created }}</small>
        </div>
        <p class="custom-p">{{ comment.text }}</p>
    </div>
{% empty %}
    <div class="list-group-item flex-column align-items-start">
        <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-center">
            <h6 class="mb-1 custom-h"><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>&#9;{% trans 'NO COMMENTS' %}</h6>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's invalid to use the same ID for multiple DOM elements. Using the same class name is valid, but will update all matching DOM elements.

My suggestion, add a unique ID to each form and comment box. If you don't want to duplicate your JS code, then add an identifier in the form that you can use to decide which comment box to update.

For example

```
<form id="task-comment-form-1" data-comment="task-comments-1">
```

Then in your JS, you could do this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.submit').on("click", function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(event.preventDefault());
        var form = $(this).closest('form');
        var commentBoxId = form.data('comment');
        var commentBox = $('#'+commentBoxId);
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr("action"),
            data: form.serialize(),
            type: form.attr("method"),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.form_is_valid) {
                    commentBox.html(data.html_task_comment);
                }
                else {
                    form.html(data.html_task_comment_form);
                }
            }
        });
        form[0].reset();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello! Can you check my post again pls. I add my html. I use {{ forloop.counter }} in ID. So now every form and block comment has unique ID. But I am little bit comfused with your JS code. It seems I need to change something in commentBoxId. What do you think?

Comment: Also the number of forms is not fixed. Here I only gave an example of 3 forms. In reality, they can be more or less than 3. In template I can use `task-comments-{{ forloop.counter }}` and `task-comment-form-{{ forloop.counter }}` but dont know how to use it in JS. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Hello. You can use the counter again in your HTML to set a `data-comment` attribute. The data comment attribute should be set to the ID you will use in your comments box. Then, the JavaScript can grab this data-comment value, use it to find the comments box specified, and update only that box.

Comment: Here is more info on using the jQuery `.data()` method to retrieve data stored in HTML (in this case, the ID attribute of the comment box to update).
https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5